# Remove all children from a group without knowing the containing nodes

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, javafx-2

check this out

```
 Group g = new Group();
 GridPane grid = new GridPane(); // 
 g.getChildren().addAll(grid);
```

now my question is how do i remove this "grid" from "g" without specifying "grid"
like something like this

```
g.getChildren().removeAll(null); //i do not know what to insert here?
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you want to remove all items from a collection, use the [`clear()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#clear--) method:

```
g.getChildren().clear();
```